# Check if a search result exists more than once if yes than display only one result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

So hi everyone. I am making an online users script using NodeJS and SocketIO. It's working normal but my problem is that if a user is connecting from several browsers/windows/devices...etc., it displays more than one result like :
`48 48 48 61` so i want that the `48` displays only once and, if he exits only one browser and others are still connected, then keep them.

Here is my code :
Client Side :

```
socket.on('userslist',function(users){
    var text = "";
    var i;
      for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        text += users[i].user_name + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      }
  });
```

Server Side :

```
socket.on('user name',function(user_name){
  users.push({id:socket.id,user_name:user_name});
  len=users.length;
  len--;
  //Sending th user Id and List of users
  io.emit('user entrance',users,users[len].id);
  io.emit('userslist',users);
});
```

I searched but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a simple optimization to your code:

```
socket.on('userslist',function(users){
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        text += users[i].user_name + "<br>";            
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text; //<-- Only needs to happen once
  });
```

Setting the `innerHTML` doesn't need to happen for every user, just once when all the text is done concatenating.

Second, keep a separate array of the traversed users to keep track of duplicates:

```
socket.on('userslist',function(users){
    var usersProcessed = [];
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(usersProcessed.indexOf(users[i].user_name) < 0){
            text += users[i].user_name + "<br>";       
            usersProcessed.push(users[i].user_name);
        } 
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  });
```

This is an example on the client, but you can do a similar thing on the server, just depends whether you need to know if there are duplicates or not. If not, it's better to do it on the server to minimize data transmission.